# Using R to filter column by male and female

Tags: r, csv, filter, tabs, dplyr

I'm trying to filter some data(CSV file) using R by male and female. Examples - I have many columns but I would like to break some of the rows into two piles one male and the other one female then run statistical analysis.

```
column1 column2 column3
34       34      male 
34       34      female
34       34      male  
34       34      female
34       34      male
```

---

I'm using dplyr to filter but I'm getting some errors with what the filter is showing me.

```
dataf <- data %>% filter(SEX == "female")
datam <- data %>% filter(SEX == "male")
dataf <- subset(data, SEX == "female")
datam <- subset(data, SEX == "male")
dataf <- filter(data, SEX == "female")
datam <- filter(data, SEX == "male")
```

---

I used three different ways but I get the same answer 0 males and the right amount for females for most of them but the last file I get 0 males and 0 females.

I did try this code to see how many female and male.

```
count <- table(data$SEX)
```

---

```
female female male male
34     0      20   0
```

---

I got a double answer one with the right answer and one with zero.
I'm guessing in some way it's taking the zero for the male column and not the 20.

Comment: You are trying to subset a colum called `SEX` but you don't show such a column in your example. Does it exist in your real data? Also, I'm unclear what your expected output is

Comment: It might be related to leading/lagging white space around `male` and `female`. Try this: `data <- read.csv("file.csv", header=TRUE, strip.white =TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE); table(data$SEX)`

Comment: Have you tried `dataf <- data[data$column3 == "female",]`?

Comment: Thank you all for the help ... I tried "data <- read.csv("file.csv", header=TRUE, strip.white =TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)"  ..... This worked out great ...  Thank you

Comment: @user5613175 can you write up your comment as an answer, submit it, and mark as closed? Thanks!